# Trouble processing wsdl file :WSDLException. Error occurred trying to resolve schema

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, wsdl, apache-axis

> 2016-06-20 10:34:09,218 [http-192.4.211.232-8080-2] INFO 
>   (org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader) - Trouble
>   processing wsdl file :WSDLException (at /definitions/types/xs:schema):
>   faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve schema
>   referenced at 'http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/swaref.xsd',
>   relative to
>   'file:/vendor/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/test/tmp/53g9qvv7g-oxqwpl-ipo49zi1-1-ipo234s1-ep/MyProject.war/WEB-INF/services/testservice/META-INF/'.: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

I am getting this error after trying to access my wsdl file once it's deployed on JBoss AS 5.1. I'm not sure why I'm getting this. This is what `/definitions/types/xs:schema` looks like:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="MyProtcol.xsd"
           xmlns="MyProtocol.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:import namespace="http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/xsd"
           schemaLocation="http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/swaref.xsd" />
```

Any idea on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the XSD `http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/swaref.xsd` is not accessible to you so

```
<xs:import namespace="http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/xsd"
           schemaLocation="http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/swaref.xsd" />
```

can not import the XSD.

Could you please confirm that you can't see the XSD from your machine `http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/swaref.xsd` ?

Comment: I used `wget` on the XSD and I cannot reach it. Weird, it was working fine yesterday.